# facebook send button ignores OG meta tags

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook Send button and I put the following on my page that shows the Send button:

**EDIT:  I have added to the code here the top of the html section of the page:**

```
 <html
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
     xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">


 <head>
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thesite.com/theHomePage.php"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Thesite is now live with a Send button!"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thesite.com/images/logo.png"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="This is test description verbiage"/>
```

**EDIT:  I added below the Send button code:**

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div> 
        <script>
        (function(d, s, id) 
        { 
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
            js = d.createElement(s); 
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
       </script>

           <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.thesite.com"></div>
```

When I use the Facebook debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, it tells me this:

```
    Raw Open Graph Document Information


   Meta Tag: <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thesite.com/theHomePage.php" />
   Meta Tag: <meta property="og:title" content="Thesite is now live with a Send button!" />
   Meta Tag: <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thesite.com/images/logo.png" />
   Meta Tag: <meta property="og:description" content="his is test description verbiage" />
```

The Facebook debugger clearly sees my Meta tags and the debugger doesn't report any problems with theHomePage.php.

So here's the problem:  When I click on the 'Send' button and the send dialog box appears:

- my 'logo.png' image is missing (despite the fact that the logo.png images DOES appear in the debugger)
- the 'Message' field is empty -- shouldn't that be filled with my **og:description** verbiage text?
- the wrong page title appears on the bottom of the Send dialog box
- and the URL shown is not http://www.thesite.com/theHomePage.php -- instead the URL shown is
  http://www.thesite.com/

Is there something else I need to do here so that my meta tags show up on the 'Send'dialog box when the
Send button is clicked?

Comment: Maybe you can share the address of the page in question, it might help. Also, please add the code of the send button in your page.

Comment: Okay, I added the other code you mentioned to my question above -- this is the first time I'm using any Facebook plugin so I'm sure I blew it somewhere but I can't see where -- the tags are in the right place and the Facebook debugger successfully finds and parses them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the info you gave in the question I assume that the url you debug is *www.thesite.com/theHomePage.php* and for that you get the expected data based on the og tags.

But from the code of the send button you gave the url of *www.thesite.com/* which is a different url.
Try to debug that url and see what you get.

Facebook index the data based on urls, and so any small difference in urls result in a different object in the graph.
Because of that you need to put the exact url in the *data-href* attribute.

Comment: Well that fixed it.  In order to make it work, I had to change the data-href in the button to match the og:url meta tag.  Now the Send dialog box appears with all my meta tags showing up (image, url, description, title).  Thanks!

Comment: The combined like- and send-button are bugged atm: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/127455164038742?browse=search_4f06766cde1d93748411610

Comment: @wantTheBest But why `data-href` and `og:url` need to be the same? I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized when they are different. But the different URLs can be accessed without problems in any browser.